# Possible to mirror iOS Safari Debug Console on a Mac, PC, or other device?

Tags: html, ios, debugging

All,

I'm working on an HTML-based web app (i.e., not native app) targeted for iPhones.

I typically use Safari's Debug Console to track down JavaScript errors; it's pretty handy.

However, when I'm working on some complex JavaScript function - it's incredibly tedious to switch back and forth between the web app and the console window. Also, there are times when I'd like to see BOTH the window and the app at the same time, so I could see console messages WHILE I'm interacting with the app.

So - is it possible to "mirror" the Debug Console to another device, or too a Mac or PC?

In other words - I'd like to be able to use a web app (or web page) on my iPhone, and have the output from `console.log()` (or `.warn()` or `.error()` or `.info()`) show up in a window on my development machine.

Adobe has something called ***Shadow*** (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/) that looks like it does something *close*:

> Adobe® Shadow is a new inspection and preview tool that allows
>   front-end web developers and designers to work faster and more
>   efficiently by streamlining the preview process, making it easier to
>   customize websites for mobile devices.

... but it's *not quite* what I'm looking for. (At least, it doesn't sound like it from the description).

Sorry in advance - I'm pretty new to this type of development, so I'm probably unaware of some tool that everyone else knows.

Either way - thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I also wish to have such a tool, but I do not think it exists. :(  I would like an IDE that included a javascript debugger, but everyone has pointed me to using the individual browsers.  I also have the issue of wanting to mimic each browser type, and so I have to use each browsers debug window, and they are different, so it means I have had to learn them all.  Not super great, but that is how I do it.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe Shadow? It does what you describe in your question but it's still quite buggy from my experience using it.

Comment: Marcel - thanks for the tip. I've tried Adobe Shadow, and it doesn't look like it quite does what I was looking for. As far as I can tell - it allows you to connect one or more mobile devices to your PC or Mac Desktop. Then, as you browse on that desktop, the connected mobile devices will "follow" along. However, if you browse on the mobile device, your desktop will not follow. In other words, it doesn't appear to be bidirectional. Moreover - it doesn't appear that any console.log messages that are generated on the mobile device appear on the desktop, which is what I was REALLY looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsconsole.com can do this. Read http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html for more info.

http://youtu.be/Y219Ziuipvc shows you how to do it.

Comment: Wow. This works great - exactly what I was looking for. And couldn't be easiser. Many thanks, Rich!

Answer (score 1):

[**weinre**](http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/) does exactly what you're wanting. Their docs are reasonably thorough so I'll let them tell [what you need to do](http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/) to get it running.

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) actually offer a [mobile web app debugging tool](http://debug.phonegap.com/) that is powered by [weinre](http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/) and is a cinch to set up so you might want to check that out first.